# Find the area of ​the shaded region

Tags: calculus

I have the curves,
$$y=4-x^{2},\hspace{4mm}\left\{\begin{array}{l}x=2+2\cos(t)\\y=2+2\sin(t)\end{array}\right.$$
I have to do it using polar coordinates, I already made the transformations:
$$r_{1}(\theta)=\pm\sqrt{4\sin\left(2\theta\right)}+2\sin\left(\theta\right)+2\cos\left(\theta\right),\hspace{5mm}r_{2}(\theta)=\frac{\pm\sqrt{16\cos^{2}\left(\theta\right)+\sin^{2}\left(\theta\right)}-\sin\left(\theta\right)}{2\cos^{2}\left(\theta\right)}$$
the point of intersection I am almost certain that it is $\theta=1.37$ but I have problems to raise the integral.

Comment: What is the shaded region?

Comment: By shaded region, do you mean the intersection of the half-space below the parabola $y = 4-x^2$ and the interior of the circle $(x-2)^2+(y-2)^2 = 2^2$? BTW, why polar coordinates, carry out the integral looks horrible.

Comment: Exact! Haha ... the idea is that we practice the change of coordinates, find the limits of integration (sometimes you have to use Newton-Rhapson), and leave the integral of the area expired. The numerical value lets us use a calculator, or make approximations. In essence I have problems in planning the integral, I already tried but in geogebra the results do not add up.

Comment: Could you help me by confirming the intersection point of the curves, and the integral approach. And another question, to make the integration through parametrics as I realize the sign I should take? But this question is more curiosity

Comment: Let $\alpha = \left(\frac{\sqrt{29}}{3^{3/2}}+\frac{28}{27}\right)^{1/3}$. According to CAS (I use maxima), the two curves intersect at first quadrant at $(x_0,y_0)$ where
$$\begin{cases}
x_0 &= \alpha + \frac{1}{9\alpha} - \frac23 \approx 0.6956207695598622\\
y_0 &= \frac14 - x_0^2 \approx 3.516111744956945\end{cases}$$
This implies the $\theta$ you seek is $\tan^{-1}\frac{y_0}{x_0} \approx 1.375480405218211$. For $r_1(\theta)$, the sign is '-', you are dealing with the part of circle closer to origin. For $r_2(\theta)$, the sign has to be '+' , otherwise, $r_2$ will be negative.

Comment: Checked your formula for $r_1(\theta)$ and $r_2(\theta)$, they looks fine.